# Smoothly increase a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game where you can earn money at a steady rate (ex. 50 dollars a second). However, when increasing "money", I want it to smoothly increase, not jump 50 dollars every second.

```js
setInterval(increasemoney,1000);
function increasemoney() {
  money = money + moneypersecond;
}
```

My current strategy is to divide it into two categories; one where you earn 1 dollar per 1/moneypersecond seconds (where moneypersecond < 1000), and one where you earn y dollars per 0.001 seconds.

However, there are two issues; <strike>because I want to avoid floats, y has to be rounded, but that will lose precision.</strike> Edit: Floats are FINE! I can also increase precision by increasing the time between "updates" (which also makes it look less smooth, and only increases precision instead of removing the imprecision).

My questions:

- Is this the right track?
- How should I implement the solution? (Preferably in a way that removes imprecision)

Requirements: <strike>I want to avoid floats</strike> Edit: Floats are okay, and the more accurate the better.

Comment: Why not use a number with decimals and only show the whole number when you display it to the user? Seems impossible to have precision without having precision.

Comment: You want to `lerp` the value, see [_Linear Interpolation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for details. See also `slerp`, [_Spherical Linear Interpolation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).

Comment: setInterval will not be exactly one second btw depending on the workload of the computer/browser.

Answer (score 2):

**1. common game loop**

Here we build an example with a common `start` function that initializes your game, and an `update` function which is called every frame. Go ahead and change `target` in realtime to watch the output `lerp` to its destination -

```js
let money;
let target;

// initialize
function start ()
{ money = document.forms.example.money
  target = document.forms.example.target
}

// each frame
function update (delta)
{ const next = lerp(Number(money.value), Number(target.value), delta/1e2)
  money.value = next.toFixed(2)
}

// helpers
function lerp (v0, v1, t, p = 1e-3)
{ const next = (1 - t) * v0 + t * v1
  if (Math.abs(v1 - next) < p)
    return v1
  else
    return next
}

function sleep (ms)
{ return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)) }

function time ()
{ let now = Date.now()
  let last
  return _ =>
  { last = now
    now = Date.now()
    return now - last
  }
}

async function loop ()
{ const deltaTime = time()
  await start()               // call `start` to initialize
  while (true)
  { await update(deltaTime()) // call `update` each frame
    await sleep(50)
  }
}

// run the game
loop()
```

```html
<form id="example">
  target: <input type="number" name="target" value="3000">
  &larr; try a big value like <b>99999999</b><br>
  money: <output name="money">0.00</output><br>
</form>
```

---

**2. vanilla html form**

If you want to see this working outside of a typical game loop situation, we can demonstrate the same thing in a basic Html form. `lerp` implementation here (same as above) is adapted from Wikipedia's [*Linear Interpolation article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) -

```js
function lerp (v0, v1, t, p = 1e-3)
{ const next = (1 - t) * v0 + t * v1
  if (Math.abs(v1 - next) < p)
    return v1
  else
    return next
}

function sleep (ms)
{ return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)) }

async function onSubmit (event)
{ // prevent default form behaviour
  event.preventDefault()

  // get input values from form as Number
  const f = event.target
  let from = Number(f.from.value)
  let to = Number(f.to.value)

  // lerp loop!
  do
  { f.output.value = from.toFixed(2)
    from = lerp(from, to, 0.33)
    await sleep(50)
  } while(from < to)
}

// attach form listener
document.forms.example.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit)
```

```html
<form id="example">
  from: <input name="from" value="100"><br>
  to: <input name="to" value="3000"><br>
  output: <output name="output"></output><br>
  <button type="submit">Lerp it!</button>
</form>
```

---

**3. vanilla html form with generator**

We can also implement `lerp` as a generator which drastically reduces the complexity of the `onSubmit` listener -

```js
function* lerp (v0, v1, t, p = 1e-3)
{ do
  { yield v0
    v0 = (1 - t) * v0 + t * v1
  } while (Math.abs(v1 - v0) > p)
  yield v1
}

function sleep (ms)
{ return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)) }

async function onSubmit (event)
{ event.preventDefault()
  const f = event.target

  // iterate over lerp generator
  for (const v of lerp(Number(f.from.value), Number(f.to.value), 0.33))
  { f.output.value = v.toFixed(2)
    await sleep(50)
  }
}

document.forms.example.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit)
```

```html
<form id="example">
  from: <input name="from" value="123.45"><br>
  to: <input name="to" value="3000.99"><br>
  output: <output name="output"></output><br>
  <button type="submit">Lerp it!</button>
</form>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is you should keep track of the decimals internally in your code. When you display the values to users, just do not show them the decimals. Use floor() to just show the whole number.

This is over kill for what you are asking, but below is showing how I have multiple things doing calcs and how showing the whole numbers to the user.

```js
class TimerCalc {
  constructor(incAmt, interval, updater) {
    this.incAmt = incAmt;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.updater = updater;
    this.lastTimeRun = performance.now();
    this.calc();
  }
  calc() {
    const diff = performance.now() - this.lastTimeRun;
    this.lastTimeRun = performance.now();

    const incAmt = diff / this.interval * this.incAmt;
    this.updater(incAmt);

    this.timer = window.setTimeout(() => this.calc(), 10);
  }
  kill() {
    this.timer && window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
}

class Bank {
  constructor(initialAmount, outputSelector) {
    this.funds = initialAmount || 0;
    this.outputElem = document.querySelector(outputSelector);
    this.timers = {};
  }
  updateAccount(diff) {
    this.funds += diff;
    this.updateScreen();
  }
  updateScreen() {
    this.outputElem.textContent = Math.floor(this.funds).toLocaleString();
  }
  addResource(name, rate, interval) {
    this.timers[name] = new TimerCalc(rate, interval, this.updateAccount.bind(this));
  }
}

const myBank1 = new Bank(0, '#out1');
myBank1.addResource("fast", 1, 1000);

const myBank2 = new Bank(0, '#out2');
myBank2.addResource("slow", 1, 10000);

const myBank3 = new Bank(0, '#out3');
myBank3.addResource("mine1", 1, 10);
myBank3.addResource("worker1", -1.50, 1000);
myBank3.addResource("worker2", -2.50, 1000);
myBank3.addResource("manager", -5.50, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="out1"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>
<div id="out3"></div>
```

Comment: the main disadvantage to this approach is that the time required to tween from `value` to `target` scales based on the difference. if the difference is large, it will take a large amount of time to reach the target. see my answer for an alternative that uses linear interpolation to reach any target in a user-specified time.

Comment: @Thankyou Your code does not appear to take into consideration that setTimeout is not a perfect 50 milliseconds. My code has a flaw there is a small time span the value is not up to date. If I would need it, I would do the calculation a different way, but for a basic cookie clicker script it works fine.

Comment: my script does pass `deltaTime` to `update` allowing the user to scale the calculation according to the precise time passed per frame. other than that, i don't really understand your comment.